# how to merge two json_arrays in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I need to `MERGE` two `JSONB_ARRAYS`

i have in my table column `jsonb` of items which looks like this:

```
[
   {"fav": 1, "is_active": true, "date": "1999-00-00 11:07:05.710000"},
   {"fav": 2, "is_active": true, "date": "1998-00-00 11:07:05.710000"}
]
```

where fav's value is unique number.

And i have incoming data, where could be the same items which also exists in my table and also new items and after merging the result must be that way where new items just need to add but existing items i need to update

so after merging the result must look like this:

```
merge:
[
   {"fav": 1, "is_active": true, "date": "1999-00-00 11:07:05.710000"},
   {"fav": 2, "is_active": true, "date": "1998-00-00 11:07:05.710000"}
]::jsonb ||

[
   {"fav": 3, "is_active": true, "date": "2019-00-00 11:07:05.710000"},
   {"fav": 1, "is_active": false, "date": "2020-00-00 11:07:05.710000"}
]::jsonb

------------------------------------------------------------------------
result:

[
   {"fav": 1, "is_active": false, "date": "2020-00-00 11:07:05.710000"},
   {"fav": 2, "is_active": true, "date": "1998-00-00 11:07:05.710000"},
   {"fav": 3, "is_active": true, "date": "2019-00-00 11:07:05.710000"}
]
```

as expected the `"fav": 1` -> was updated and `"fav": 3` -> was added
maybe i need some refactroring structure of my `json` maybe something else?
and maybe it would be better if i retrieve json to Collection and work with objects and after all manipulations just save it back?

#### Update 1

i try write custom function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_array_merge(data1 jsonb, merge_data jsonb)
    RETURNS jsonb
    IMMUTABLE
    LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
SELECT jsonb_agg(expression)::jsonb
FROM (
         WITH to_merge AS (
             SELECT * FROM jsonb_each(jsonb_array_elements(merge_data))
         )
         SELECT *
         FROM json_each(jsonb_array_elements(data1))
         WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM to_merge)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT * FROM to_merge
     ) expression;
$$;
```

but now it doesnt work (

Answer (score 0):

You probably will want to write a custom function to handle this. The default behaviour is to append each value because it has no way of knowing that you want `fav` to be unique.

If your data used fav as a key e.g.

```
{
    "fav1": {"date": "2020-00-00 11:07:05.710000", "is_active": false},
    "fav2": {"date": "1998-00-00 11:07:05.710000", "is_active": true},
    "fav3": {"date": "2019-00-00 11:07:05.710000", "is_active": true}
}
```

this would be simple to manage, but since you are using an array you would need to make a custom function that iterates and check each value.

Edit you would need to run a few loops with plpgsql, this could be achieved more efficiently using plv8

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_array_merge(
    data_new jsonb,
    data_old jsonb,
    key_val text
)
    RETURNS jsonb
AS $$
DECLARE
    ret jsonb := '[]'::jsonb;
    cur text;
    add boolean := true;

    i integer := 0;
    ic integer := jsonb_array_length(data_old);
    j integer := 0;
    jc integer := jsonb_array_length(data_new);
BEGIN
    IF ic > 0 AND jc > 0 THEN

        -- populate or replace the records that are already there
        WHILE i < ic LOOP
            cur := null;
            j   := 0;

            -- loop new array
            WHILE j < jc LOOP
                IF data_old->i->>key_val = data_new->j->>key_val THEN
                    cur := data_new->>j;
                    add := false;
                END IF;
                j := j + 1;
            END LOOP;

            -- add or replace
            IF add THEN
                ret := ret || format('[%s]', data_old->>i)::jsonb;
            ELSE
                ret := ret || format('[%s]', cur)::jsonb;
            END IF;

            add := true;
            i   := i + 1;
        END LOOP;

        -- loop through the new data again and add any values not in ret
        ic := jsonb_array_length(ret);
        j  := 0;
        WHILE j < jc LOOP
            i   := 0;
            add := true;

            WHILE i < ic LOOP
                IF ret->i->>key_val = data_new->j->>key_val THEN
                    add := false;
                END IF;

                i := i + 1;
            END LOOP;

            IF add THEN
                ret := ret || format('[%s]', data_new->>j)::jsonb;
            END IF;

            j := j + 1;
        END LOOP;
    ELSE
        ret := data_new;
    END IF;

    RETURN ret;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Running this should give you the desired result

```
SELECT json_array_merge(
    '[{"fav": 3, "is_active": true, "date": "2019-00-00 11:07:05.710000"},{"fav": 1, "is_active": false, "date": "2020-00-00 11:07:05.710000"}]',
    '[{"fav": 1, "is_active": true, "date": "1999-00-00 11:07:05.710000"},{"fav": 2, "is_active": true, "date": "1998-00-00 11:07:05.710000"}]',
    'fav'
)
```

Comment: absolutely agree with you. but how i can use fav's values as a keys??

Comment: That should give you what you need, but there are more efficient methods